# How do I translate swipe speed and position to object velocity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am developing a "kick the fieldgoal" type game for the purpose of teaching myself Unity 3d. I have the interface and functionality I want, such that the game looks like this:

[image]

I'm using some code in OnUpdate to detect when the mouse button is first pressed (or touch phase begins) and when it is released (or touch phase ends) and calculate the swipe direction, distance and duration.  I want to translate this information into an initial velocity to "launch" the football, but the math is slightly beyond me, it seems.

I started with something like this:

```
rigidbody.velocity = new Vector3(
    Mathf.Min(15, swipeDelta.x * .13f),
    Mathf.Min(20, swipeDelta.y * yRatio),
    5 / swipeDuration);
```

This of course worked well at my initial resolution and aspect ratio, but fails miserably as soon as I change either one. I'd like the code to be more resolution and aspect ratio agnostic, or at least, relative. The numbers used in the code above are completely arbitrary and were discovered to produce desirable results at my initial resolution based on iterative testing.

Any suggestions?

Comment: you have two points A (first click) and B (click release), then B minus A gives you the direction from which you can get the magnitude (aka length aka velocity aka "speed"). You can then normalize this direction and multiply it with a given (fixed or variable) speed factor to ensure your ball flies out in that direction at an appropriate speed (otherwise the velocity may be too low or too high because mouse coordinates don't directly translate to physics velocity).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to take the distance and duration between the start and end point and use them for the velocity.

I use ScreenToWorldPoint to get the mouse position from screen coordinates to world coordinates so that its the distance in the world that counts, not the pixel density or resolution of the screen.

The expected min/max values are the values of power you get before any adjustments are made. To get good values you do a slow/short swipe for min and a fast long for max.

The desired min/max values are your arbitrary values that makes desirable results.

You might need to rotate the velocity depending on how your game is orientated. Right now a swipe up gives positive y values and a swipe right gives positive x values.

```
Vector3 startPos;
float startTime;

void Update () 
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        //Store initial values
        startPos = Input.mousePosition;
        startTime = Time.time;
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        //Get end values
        Vector3 endPos = Input.mousePosition;
        float endTime = Time.time;

        //Mouse positions distance from camera. Might be a better idea to use the cameras near plane
        startPos.z = 0.1f
        endPos.z = 0.1f

        //Makes the input pixel density independent
        startPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(startPos);
        endPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(endPos);

        //The duration of the swipe
        float duration = endTime - startTime;

        //The direction of the swipe
        Vector3 dir = endPos - startPos;

        //The distance of the swipe
        float distance = dir.magnitude;

        //Faster or longer swipes give higher power
        float power = distance / duration;

        //expected values are what power you get when you try 
        //desired values are what you want
        //you might want these as public values so they can be set from the inspector
        const float expectedMin = 50;
        const float expectedMax = 60;
        const float desiredMin = 15;
        const float desiredMax = 20;

        //Measure expected power here
        Debug.Log(power);

        //change power from the range 50...60 to 0...1
        power -= expectedMin;
        power /= expectedMax - expectedMin;

        //clamp value to between 0 and 1
        power = Mathf.Clamp01(power);

        //change power to the range 15...20
        power *= desiredMax - desiredMin;
        power += desiredMin;

        //take the direction from the swipe. length of the vector is the power
        Vector3 velocity = (transform.rotation * dir).normalized * power
    }
```

Comment: This worked, even without the extra min/max stuff (though I may add that in later for sanity). However, I had to add a Z vector to the mouse position vectors, or the ScreenToWorldPoint method returned the same vector every time. I found this from the answer to the question at http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/331558/screentoworldpoint-not-working.html

Comment: I did not have that problem when i tested the code. Maybe we have different versions of unity. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Now I've rotated the camera and the ball object to look at the goal post (since the idea is to randomly move the camera angle to simulate a position on the field) but the velocity is still applied relative to the X angle being zero. How can I translate the X property of the velocity relative to the direction the ball is facing?

Comment: Depends on how you apply the power. If you are using force with a rigidbody you can simply use `rigidbody.AddRelativeForce`. If you are using velocity you need to give the power the same rotation as the ball by doing `power *= ball.transform.rotation` or something along those lines.

Comment: I can't multiply a float (power) by a quaternion (rotation). Essentially, my problem is that if the ball is rotated 20degrees to the right around the y axis, I need the x value of the velocity to represent that. Right now, the x value of the velocity is relative to the world coordinates (0.0 being straight toward the end of the field, rather than straight in the direction the ball is facing).

Comment: sorry i meant `ball.transform.rotation * dir` this will rotate the dir of the velocity the same way the ball is rotated. So the final result will be `Vector3 velocity = (ball.transform.rotation * dir).normalized * power`

Comment: I apologize for being a dunce. I tried what you said and it appears to fix the X direction issue, but then the Y and Z components are all hosed. Can you take a look at the gist here (https://gist.github.com/ripvannwinkler/800de7277914002c61d8) and tell me if you see what I'm doing wrong? The key function is SetBallInMotion.