# Unity 3D Ball Follow the finger

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a 3d game like ketchapp ball race, in which the cube slides along a road, and the left right movement is controlled using touch

The problem I am facing is that the touch senstivity seems to react different on different devices, due to which I am not able to calculate the left-right displacement for all devices.
This is how I am calculating the left-right  displacement of the cube:

```
     Vector2 touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition ;
     transform.Translate(touchDeltaPosition.x * .1f * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
```

However this is not working properly all device . Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Do you factor in the different screen resolution of different devices?

Answer (score 3):

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25740565/10063126

Basically, **ScreenToWorldPoint** was used.
World position is computed; not screen touch position.

But you have to manually solve for delta position.

Example:

```
Vector3 currPos  = Input.mousePosition;
Vector3 startPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(currPos);
Vector3 endPos   = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(prevPos);

Vector3 deltaPos = endPos - startPos;
transform.Translate(deltaPos.x * sensitivity * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);    

prevPos = currPos;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using 2 buttons on your screen one for left control and one for right control and then when the left button is pressed you can give a value to go left and same for right button. This way your ball's movement will be independent from the touched position's X value.